# Is there a mistake in this Google Apps Script documentation page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm reading the GAS documentation on scriptProperties and I found this:

[image]

Should the keyword `special` be between within quotation marks? (this way: `ScriptProperties.setProperties({'special': 'sauce', 'meaning': 42}, true);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its valid javascript. Did you try it?

Comment: While it might be less confusing to use the same format on object properties, javascript allows such mixed ways to define object properties.